# Create a unique Integer for each string?

Tags: haskell

How can I hash a string in haskell to get a more-or-less unique hash value. For example:

```
hash:: String -> Integer

>hash "foo"
1234123412
>hash "bar"
5938454
```

Or something along those lines? I'm not familiar with hashing in haskell so any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Treat the string as a number in base maxBound::Char.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [hashable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hashable/latest/doc/html/Data-Hashable.html) package from Hackage. It provides hash functions for a number of standard types, including strings:

```
Prelude Data.Hashable> hash "foo"
653367
Prelude Data.Hashable> hash "bar"
649056
```

If you want to implement your own, hash functions are usually easy to express as a fold. For example, here's a variant of the DJB2 hash:

```
hash :: String -> Int
hash = foldl' (\h c -> 33*h `xor` fromEnum c) 5381
```

Note that these hash functions are meant to be simple and fast. If you're looking for more complex hash functions, you can find a selection in the [cryptohash](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptohash) package.

Comment: Thanks, that is great, but is there something a bit more "random" looking? Currently for "agent1" and "agent2" it produces consecutive numbers... :-(

Comment: You can spread the hashes to avoid that by multiplying each `fromEnum c` with a largish prime (modulo 2^32, say).

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized I use hash as a seed to my randomR function, so it's o'l good!